# Firefox not random support mask-image over text

Tags: html, css, mask

Two Macbook pros, same site, one renders and one doesn't. All text with the texture class doesn't show on pages randomly on both computers. Jekyll renders all link properly.

Bug?

```
.texture {
    -webkit-mask-image:url('{{site.url }}/img/texture.png');
    mask-image:url('{{site.url }}/img/texture.png');
    mask:url('{{site.url }}/img/texture.png');
    -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
    mask-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    mask-size: contain;
}
```

Link to a video of the issue from our test site https://test.88k.com.tw/firefox-bug.MOV

Comment: Chrome, Safari are fine.

Comment: What FF version? It's supported only after 53 version: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Firefox 62.0 Quantum. Just posted a video to show the problem. Link to a video of the issue from our test site https://test.88k.com.tw/firefox-bug.MOV

Comment: When I remove the -webkit-mask-size: contain and 
    mask-size: contain from the texture class, Firefox seems to at least show text, but the effect is not as intended.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with `mask-size: contain;`.  If you set it to `auto` (which is the initial value) it shows the mask just fine.

Comment: Nice! I was just gonna try that. Thx Joesph!

Comment: @Kevin well, I wouldn't thank me just yet.  That seems to be the property causing the issue, but at the same time, it doesn't explain why it's happening.  Maybe when FF tries to resize it, it's loosing the white bits?  sub-pixel anti-aliasing maybe?

Comment: Well, doesn't quite work right. The images mask is too big and the texture doesn't appear as it should, like on Chrome and Safari. The test domain will show you if you compare on different browsers.

Comment: Ok, thought I figured it out. My image was a png. I converted it to svg and seems to works in FF, but not in other browsers

Comment: Try the PNG again but instead use `mask-size: auto 100%;`.  Does that get the right texture across browsers?

Comment: Alright, here we go  -webkit-mask-image use png and for mask-image use svg

Comment: @Kevin Good idea.  I suppose that would work.  Just be aware that it might break in the future if Chrome adopts the official syntax and drops support for the `-webkit-` prefix.